# How to set a the value of a JavaScript Variable from my ViewData in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-5, viewdata

I am doing some client side calculations in a JavaScript function. And for that I need a value from Server. I have set the value in ViewData["Period"] in ASP.NET MVC 5 controller and in my view I want to set this ViewData["Period"] in JavaScript variable so that when the page loads the value is loaded in that javascript variable from viewdata.

```
var corporateInfo;


function getRates(startDate,deliveryDate)
{
    //Do some calculation on client side based on corporateInfo,startDate, deliveryDate
}

function(areaCode)
{
// Do some calculation based on corporateInfo and areaCode
}
```

How to set the periodInfo in my asp.net mvc 5 view from ViewData when the page loads.?

Edited: Aug18
corporateInfo is class with several properties in it and one of the property returns array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Asp.net MVC view I have added the below code.
Because Corporate was a complex object that's what I had to serialize it first and then assign it to the JavaScript variable.
For serializing C# complex object to json I have used JavaScriptSerializer class which is in System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace.

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization

<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jss.Serialize(ViewData["Corporate"]);
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("corporateInfo = {0};", json));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you can insert a small snippet of JavaScript that sets a global variable:

```
<script>
Period = @ViewData["Period"]
</script>
```

That will render to a script that sets the global `Period` variable with the current value from `ViewData`, then you can access that variable from your calculation script.

Since the variable is global, you might want to give it a longer name to guarantee that it will be unique.